# Best practices for “show password” functionality

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, password

In a mobile app context, when the user is presented with a dialog specifically asking for a password, what are the best practices for allowing the user to show the password while entering it into the field?

In particular, I’m wondering about:

- writing “show password” versus using an eye icon.
- the location of the element (see locations 1 through 4 in the image), especially when trying . Using an eye icon in position 3 is common but can be problematic with long passwords.
- showing the password only when pressed versus toggling visibility on/off with each press.

[image]

Comment: An important factor here is expectations: what is the standard for the OS or platform? What's recommended in the design guidelines? What are the top applications for that platform doing?

Answer (score 3):

> writing “show password” versus using an eye icon.

Both options are widely used.

**Better still, use an eye icon with a label that says ''Show/Hide Password" so it's clear what the icon means.**

Or If you want to save real estate for the input field, you can shift the action below the field so you can either have an icon or a checkbox to clearly mention the action.

[image]

> showing the password only when pressed versus toggling visibility
> on/off with each press.

This is an accessibility concern. Users with dexterity/motor issues will find difficulty in 'touch and hold' the button, also users with cognitive related issues will have a hard time remembering what they just saw.

Also from a usability perspective, studies have shown that it is better to keep the password unmasked on mobile screens by default.

[According to Luke Wroblewski:](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1653)

> there’s a visible touch keyboard directly below the input field that
> highlights each key as you press it. These bits of feedback show the
> characters in a password at a larger size than most input fields. So
> in reality, the •••• characters aren’t really hiding a password from
> prying eyes anyway

Related Articles:

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/

https://cxl.com/blog/password-ux/